# Validate valid phone number entry

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to figure out invalid phone numbers entered in edittext before hitting the OTP api. Invalid phone numbers pattern may looks like these patterns **+91-0000000000 / +91-0000000011 / +91-1234567890** ...and so on.  Already added a check to validate invalid phone number but it didn't helps in detecting invalid patterns of phone numbers which can't exist.

```
private boolean isValidMobile(String phone) {
return android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(phone).matches();    
}
```

Anyone please suggest how to handle these numbers before hitting the OTP api. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the documentation says, "This pattern is intended for searching for things that look like they might be phone numbers in arbitrary text, not for validating whether something is in fact a phone number. It will miss many things that are legitimate phone numbers."

Comment: PhoneNumberUtils. isGlobalPhoneNumber might be a better API.

Answer (score 2):

To validate a 10 digit Mobile number, here is a working code. Hope this works for you too.

```
String number = binding.editNumber.getText().toString();
// isPhoneValid = isValidMobileNo(number);
if (isValidMobileNo(number)) {
        isPhoneValid = true;
else {
        Log.d("Result: ","Not Valid");
        isPhoneValid = false;
        valid = false;
}

private boolean isValidMobileNo(String str) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(0/91)?[6-9][0-9]{9}");
    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(str);
    return (match.find() && match.group().equals(str));
}
```

Test Sample can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eugHF.png), an error message set to the EditText can be seen in this example.

Comment: I want to validate if number is valid or not means if user enter 10 digit number as 0000000000 then your logic is returning true.

Comment: @KapilRajput Let me check with this condition

Comment: @KapilRajput When I tried the same number 0000000000, it returned false

Comment: pattern here will return false if number after 0/91 is other than 6 to 9.